# Not able to use pushPayload in ember

Tags: ajax, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have to store a data from ajax call to model.Now I am using "pushPayload" to save the data to my model.But it is throwing  error

```
serializer.pushPayload is not a function
```

In controller I am doing something like this after the ajax call.

```
currentState.store.pushPayload('discover',result)
```

serializer (discover.js)

```
export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,{
isNewSerializerAPI: true,
  primaryKey:'pk',
  normalize: function(typeClass, hash) {
    var fields = Ember.get(typeClass, 'fields');
    fields.forEach(function(field) {
      var payloadField = Ember.String.underscore(field);
      if (field === payloadField) { return; }
      hash[field] = hash[payloadField];
      delete hash[payloadField];
    });
    return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  }
  });
```

How do I save the data recieved from server to my model.The reponse is an array of object

Comment: What is `currentState` ? Normally you see `this.get('store').pushPayload('discover', result)` when you want to use pushPayload (assuming the `store` service is available there (route/controller) or was injected

Comment: @PedroRio current state is variable for "this"

Comment: If you `console.log(currentState)` and `console.log(currentState.store)` do you get the controller instance and store instance printed in the console?

Comment: @PedroRio I am getting something like this       Class {_backburner: Backburner, typeMaps: Object, recordArrayManager: Class, _pendingSave: Array[0], _instanceCache: ember$data$lib$system$store$container$instance$cache$$ContainerInstanceCache…}

Comment: It does seem to be the store. A least it looks what my store outputs as well. Assuming there's a pushPayload function there, I can only assume that the place where you get the error is not using the DS.Store instance.

Comment: what should I do in this case ?

Comment: If you can recreate an working example that causes the issue in an ember-twiddle or in a github repository, I might be able to take a look. Without that there are two many possibilities to discuss here.

Answer (score 1):

store.pushPayload internally uses either application serializer's pushPayload function or the given model's specific serializer's pushPayload function. In your case model specific serializer is of JSONSerializer type which doesn't have the required function.

You can refer [JSONAPISerialzer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html), which has the pushPayload function and try to replica it in your [JSONSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONSerializer.html).